# Jquery : how to prevent div function?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

I have a div show hide function which is working fine.
when I click next button it showing next div unfortunately I don't how to prevent the next function when the fivs are finished. I can show you my so far works here

```
    <div id="prev">Prev</div >
    <div id="next">Next</div >
    <hr /> 

<div id="main">   
    <div id="div1" class="first current">Div 1</div>
    <div id="div2">Div 2</div>
    <div id="div3" class="last">Div 3</div>    
</div>
​
$('#next').click(function() {
    $('.current').removeClass('current').hide().next().show().addClass('current');
    if ($('.current').hasClass('last')) {
        $('#next').attr('disabled', true);
    }
    $('#prev').attr('disabled', null);
});

$('#prev').click(function() {
    $('.current').removeClass('current').hide().prev().show().addClass('current');
    if ($('.current').hasClass('first')) {
        $('#prev').attr('disabled', true);
    }
    $('#next').attr('disabled', null);
});​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sweetmaanu/LY6wY/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this for `next` click

```
if ($('.current').next().length)
    // the rest of the code
```

and for `prev` click:

```
if ($('.current').prev().length)
    // the rest of the code
```

See [the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LY6wY/5/).

Answer (score 3):

There is no `disabled` attribute for a `div`. If you make your next and previous buttons be actual `<button>s`, it will work http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/LY6wY/4/

If you want to use `div`s, you can follow mshsayem's suggestion, which needs is much simpler to look at. Or you can use Rodolfo's suggestion, which makes the code longer, but allows you to style the disabled divs differently

```
$(function() {
  var $next = $('#next'),
      $prev = $('#prev');

    $next.click(function () {
      if ($next.hasClass('disabled')) {
        return;
      }
      $('.current').removeClass('current').hide().next().show().addClass('current');
      if ($('.current').hasClass('last')) {
        $next.addClass('disabled');
      }
      $prev.removeClass('disabled');
  });

  $prev.click(function () {
      if ($prev.hasClass('disabled')) {
        return;
      }

      $('.current').removeClass('current').hide().prev().show().addClass('current');
      if ($('.current').hasClass('first')) {
        $prev.addClass('disabled');
      }
      $next.removeClass('disabled');
  });
});
```

Comment: that, or use 'disabled' as a class instead, and check if the div has has that class in the 'prev' and 'next' click functions

Comment: @Rodolfo Since there divs already have a first and last, mshayem's suggestion will be simpler. However, adding the CSS disabled property would allow you to style the div so it looks disabled

Answer (score 2):

[As an alternative to the solution above(Juan Mendes)]
Slightly modified (and it works):

```
$('#next').click(function() {
    if ($('.current').hasClass('last'))return; 
    $('.current').removeClass('current').hide().next().show().addClass('current');

});

$('#prev').click(function() {
      if ($('.current').hasClass('first'))return;
      $('.current').removeClass('current').hide().prev().show().addClass('current');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply forget about `first`, `last` and `current` class. Try this:

```
$('#next').click(function() {
    $('#main > div:visible').hide()
        .next().show();
    if ($('#main > div:visible').attr('id') === 'div3') {
        $(this).hide();
    }
    $('#prev').show();
});   
$('#prev').click(function() {
    $('#main > div:visible').hide()
        .prev().show();

    if ($('#main > div:visible').attr('id') === 'div1') {
        $(this).hide();
    }
    $('#next').show();
});
​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LY6wY/8/

Comment: It works, but I would much prefer to use `first` and `last` when testing in code than using `div1` and `div3`, keeps the code easier to read. I would prefer the ditch the `div[x]` ids. freakish's idea does seems easy to comprehend though (detecting it by whether there is a `prev()` or `next()` div)

Comment: You can use `if ($('#main > div:visible').is(':first') or is(':last') `instead of `.attr('id') === 'div3'` and `.attr('id') === 'div1' `respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this, I think you can have it with just adding if statement.

http://jsfiddle.net/XBJbs/